# Chrome Custom tab links does not launch the app, but mobile chrome browser does

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking

I'm trying to launch my android application through a browser link.

When I open the link through the chrome browser, it successfully shows the App Dialog Picker which shows the app available for the scheme like this.

[app dialog picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7FsH.png)

**But when the link is opened through the Chrome Custom tab, 
it just redirects to the site without showing the App Dialog Picker**.

I need it to launch the app or show the dialog picker when the link is opened from another app (like gmail) which opens the in-app browser and not just in the chrome browser.

here is the current intent-filter I have.

```
            <intent-filter>
                <data 
                    android:scheme="http" 
                    android:host="www.myapp.com" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />        
            </intent-filter>
```

If anyone could point out would be a great help. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with 'the in-app browser'?

Comment: Oh, sorry for the ambigous term. The term "in-app" I was referring to is the web browser that opens within an app when a link in the app is clicked. Say for example in facebook, when you click a website link from a page, it opens it's own browser and not the default browser in the device (e.g. Chrome). It is also different from a WebView. Hope it makes sense

Comment: Dont understand. `when a link in the app is clicked`. Where would that link be displayed? And where does that browser come from? What kind of browser? How did you add it to your app?

Comment: I found the in-app browser term. It's called Chrome Custom tabs https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs . But still no luck in launching my app from it.

Answer (score 3):

So if ever anyone encounters the same problem, here's what I did. To launch your app with Chrome Custom Tabs browser, you need to make your scheme a non web-link format and make it into a custom scheme (example below). Because apparently, Chrome Custom tabs considers web link schemes as an ordinary link therefore launching it in the browser.

so from

```
            <intent-filter>
                <data 
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="www.myapp.com" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />        
            </intent-filter>
```

change the scheme to a custom one, that way, your app's scheme will be the only one that gets handled by the browser. This is an example link with the scheme given below ~ myapp://myapp.app (note that this link is not clickable in android apps, but you can place it in the href of the html anchor tag of your website).

```
        <intent-filter>
            <data 
                android:scheme="myapp" 
                android:host="myapp.app" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />        
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: This seems to be correct, but do you have any official documentation where this is stated?